# Search and Filter in Primefaces Column Group Headers

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When primefaces datatable column headers used for filtering and sorting, it works fine.I want to add column groups to headers, but in that case filtering and sorting seems not possible.

```
<p:dataTable id="tb1" value="#{hrReportController.staffShiftHistorys}" var="ss"
             rows="20" paginator="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
                        {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputLabel value="Shift Amendments" style="font-size: 20px"/>
  </f:facet>

  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Changed at" sortBy="#{ss.createdAt}"/>
      <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Changed by"
                sortBy="#{ss.creater.webUserPerson.name}"
                filterBy="#{ss.creater.webUserPerson.name}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>
      <p:column colspan="4" headerText="Changed from"/>
      <p:column colspan="4" headerText="Changed to"/>
    </p:row>
    <p:row>
      <p:column headerText="Code" sortBy="#{ss.staff.code}"
                filterBy="#{ss.staff.code}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>
      <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{ss.staff.person.nameWithTitle}"
                filterBy="#{ss.staff.person.nameWithTitle}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>
      <p:column headerText="Roster" sortBy="#{ss.roster.name}" 
                filterBy="#{ss.roster.name}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>
      <p:column headerText="Shift"  sortBy="#{ss.shift.name}"
                filterBy="#{ss.shift.name}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>
      <p:column headerText="Code" sortBy="#{ss.staffShift.staff.code}"
                filterBy="#{ss.staffShift.staff.code}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>
      <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{ss.staffShift.staff.person.nameWithInitials}"
                filterBy="#{ss.staffShift.staff.person.nameWithInitials}" 
                filterMatchMode="contains"/>
      <p:column headerText="Roster" sortBy="#{ss.staffShift.roster.name}"
                filterBy="#{ss.staffShift.roster.name}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>
      <p:column headerText="Shift"sortBy="#{ss.staffShift.shift.name}"
                filterBy="#{ss.staffShift.shift.name}" filterMatchMode="contains"/>
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>

  <p:column headerText="Changed At">
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Changed At"/></f:facet>
    <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.createdAt}">
      <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd MMM yy- hh:mm a"/>
    </p:outputLabel>
  </p:column>     
  <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Changed by"/></f:facet>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.creater.webUserPerson.name}"/>
   </p:column>     
   <p:column >
     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Code"/></f:facet>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.staff.code}"/>
   </p:column>   
   <p:column >
     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Name"/></f:facet>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.staff.person.nameWithTitle}"/>
   </p:column>  
   <p:column >
     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Roster"/></f:facet>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.roster.name}"/>
   </p:column>   
   <p:column >
     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Shift"/></f:facet>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.shift.name}"/>
   </p:column>   
   <p:column >
     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Code"/></f:facet>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.staffShift.staff.code}"/>
   </p:column>   
   <p:column>
     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Name"/></f:facet>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.staffShift.staff.person.nameWithInitials}"/>
   </p:column>                                                           
   <p:column >
     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Roster"/></f:facet>
     <p:outputLabel value="#{ss.staffShift.roster.name}"/>
   </p:column>
   <p:column>
     <f:facet name="header"><h:outputLabel value="Shift"/></f:facet>
    <p:outputLabel value=" #{ss.staffShift.shift.name}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: PrimeFaces 0.9 does not support this

Comment: [Here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7016) it is mentioned that a `<p:dataTable>` with `<p:columnGroup type="header">` in PrimeFaces 2.2 works with sorting and filtering. "*Both filtering and sorting are now supported with `columnGroups`*".

Comment: @Buddhika Ariyaratne What exactly doesn't work in this code because it works for me if I put `<p:dataTable>` inside `<h:form>`

Comment: Works fine except there are no filters and sorters inside the header column.

Comment: When I copypaste your snippet into a blank project with PF 5.2, the currently latest community version, I'm seeing sorters and filters. Please tell what Kukeltje tried to hint: which PF version exactly are you using and have you tried the latest if any?

Comment: Ok, so now more explicit: What PrimeFaces version are/were you using here?

Comment: @BuddhikaAriyaratne, I have the same issue .If you found a solution, please share

Comment: I have the same or a similar issue (using primefaces 6.0). The filters are rendered but filterBy and filterFunction are ignored. (For testing I set up incorrect beans and it does not care - expected a javax.el.MethodNotFoundException)